# how to print Text on HBITMAP?

Tags: visual-c++

how to print Text on HBITMAP?

how to attach HBITMAP into CImage Object?

Answer (score 0):

`CImage::Attach` allows you to set the `HBITMAP` of the `CImage` object.

To draw text on the bitmap, create a device context object:

```
CDC::FromHandle (CImage::GetDC ())
```

then use the `CDC::TextOut` function to draw the text (or any of the other text drawing functions).